# How to create a GenericParameter return type for a MethodReference in Mono.Cecil?

Tags: .net, il, mono.cecil

I'm trying to reproduce the following IL using Mono.Cecil:

```
call !!0 [mscorlib]System.Threading.Interlocked::CompareExchange<class [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler>(!!0&, !!0, !!0)
```

When I use Mono.Cecil to inspect this IL, I see that the operand of the instruction is a GenericInstanceMethod, which holds an ElementMethod of type MethodReference. This MethodReference in turn has a return type of type GenericParameter.

I'd like to create the same objects by hand, but reach a catch-22 it seems. To create a GenericParameter, I need an IGenericParameterOwner, which seems to be the very same MethodReference above. So I'd like to pass the MethodReference to the GenericParameter constructor. However, I can't create the MethodReference without a TypeReference for the return type either, which I assume should be the GenericParameter.

How do I resolve this? What I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the API as it is.

An easy way to work around this would be to pass a TypeReference to void as the ReturnType of your MethodReference, and change the ReturnType to the later created GenericParameter.

Comment: Ah, so you mean I could do something like this? 
`var elementMethodRef = new MethodReference("CompareExchange", _voidTypeRef);
var genParam = new GenericParameter("!!0", elementMethodRef);
elementMethodRef.ReturnType = genParam;`

Comment: @Einar yes, and then elementMethodRef.GenericParameters.Add(genParam);

Comment: Wonderful, that was the missing piece! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it seems I still have some problems, I should provide a type of "class [System]System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler" for the generic parameter, now it seems to be empty or void?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I got it now, I need to pass a GenericArgument to the GenericInstanceMethod. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, you'll have better luck on the mono-cecil google group for trick questions like this btw.